# Copy files modified in last 24 hours to different folder name than source

Tags: file-io, vbscript

I would like to create a script that does the following:

copy from source folders "reportexport01", "reportexport02" on local drive

modified from the last 24 hours

copy to destination folders "deptreport01", "deptreport02" on share drive

I'll be using this script to create a scheduled task that runs at midnight every night and copies reports from the previous day to a departments share drive. What has me stumped is that the destination folders are named differently than the source folders. Unfortunately, I cannot change the naming scheme since other automated reports use these folders. Below is what I had as an original script that just simply copied the folders, before I knew the previous 24 hour and different folder name requirements.

```
Dim FSO
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
FSO.CopyFolder "E:\export\reportexport01", "\\sharedrive\deptreport01"
FSO.CopyFolder "E:\export\reportexport02", "\\sharedrive\deptreport02"
```

And here is what I have so far

```
Option Explicit

Dim FSO, folder, file
Dim Filepath(4)
Filepath(0)="E:\TestExport\Src01"
Filepath(1)="\\deptshare\TestExport\Dest01"
Filepath(2)="E:\TestExport\Src02"
Filepath(3)="\\deptshare\TestExport\Dest02"

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set folder = fileSystem.GetFolder(Filepath(0))

for each file in folder.Files
    if file.DateLastModified > dateadd("h", -24, Now) then
        FSO.CopyFile "Filepath(0)", "Filepath(1)"
        WScript.Echo file.Name & " last modified at " & file.DateLastModified
    end if
next

Set folder = fileSystem.GetFolder(Filepath(2))

for each file in folder.Files
    if file.DateLastModified > dateadd("h", -24, Now) then
        FSO.CopyFile "Filepath(2)", "Filepath(3)"
        WScript.Echo file.Name & " last modified at " & file.DateLastModified
    end if
```

Cleaned up after some great input from co-workers

```
Option Explicit

Dim oFSO, oFolder, oFile, i

Dim arrSourcePaths : arrSourcePaths = Array( _
                                            "E:\TestExport\Src01", _
                                            "E:\TestExport\Src02" _
                                           )

Dim arrDestinationPaths : arrDestinationPaths = Array( _
                                            "\\deptshare\TestExport\Dest01", _
                                            "\\deptshare\TestExport\Dest02" _
                                            )

oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For i = 0 To UBound(arrSourcePaths)
    oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(arrSourcePaths(i))

    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
        WScript.Echo oFile.Name & " was last modified at " & oFile.DateLastModified '
        If oFile.DateLastModified < DateAdd("h", -24, Now) Then
            oFSO.CopyFile (arrSourcePaths(i) & "\" & oFile.Name, arrDestinationPaths(i) & "\" & oFile.Name)                       
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Unfortunately, I'm given an error for the parens on the subroutine. When removed I then receive an error for oFSO = "Object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but have you considered [robocopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx)?

Comment: Thought about it G.Stoynev, but wanted to try and accomplish via vbscript first. If I can't get this functional, then I may resort to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can't use pararentheses when calling a Sub!](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/15/52996.aspx)

```
oFSO.CopyFile (arrSourcePaths(i) & "\" & oFile.Name, arrDestinationPaths(i) & "\" & oFile.Name)
```

==>

```
oFSO.CopyFile arrSourcePaths(i) & "\" & oFile.Name, arrDestinationPaths(i) & "\" & oFile.Name
```

Assignment of objects to variables needs `Set`.

```
oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
```

==>

```
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
```